# Count Frequency of the nth item of each List within Larger List

Tags: python, count, sublist

I have seen solutions for counting of values within a simple list, but what if you have a list of lists?

Example:

```
list = [[Frank, 23],[Mary, 55],[Craig, 17],[Nancy, 34],[Ben, 55],[Cindy, 47]]
```

How would I count the number of times the second value of each sublist is 55?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new generator out of it and pass it to `sum()`:

```
>>> l = [['Frank', 23],['Mary', 55],['Craig', 17],['Nancy', 34],['Ben', 55],['Cindy', 47]]
>>> sum(item[1]==55 for item in l)
2
```

Also, don't name it `list`, or that masks the built-in function `list()`.

Comment: I want to count the number of 55 year-olds, i.e. the number of times 55 occurs as the 2nd value in all substrings.  In my example the answer should be 2.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
>>> li = [['Frank', 23],['Mary', 55],['Craig', 17],['Nancy', 34],['Ben', 55],['Cindy', 47]]
```

You can invert the matrix:

```
>>> zip(*li)
[('Frank', 'Mary', 'Craig', 'Nancy', 'Ben', 'Cindy'), (23, 55, 17, 34, 55, 47)]
```

And count the 55's in the nth element:

```
>>> zip(*li)[1].count(55)
2
```

OR, you can use [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) and get the nth item:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> map(itemgetter(1), li)
[23, 55, 17, 34, 55, 47]
>>> map(itemgetter(1), li).count(55)
2
```

---

If you want ALL the counts, use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(zip(*li)[1])
Counter({55: 2, 17: 1, 34: 1, 47: 1, 23: 1})
```